# SQL Query-Group by and filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the table  as shown in below image.

[image]

I am trying to get the latest `status_id`, grouped by `team_id` and based on max of `created_date`.

```
 --Latest status for each team based on created date
SELECT *
FROM  ProductionHistory
WHERE created_Date IN (
                      SELECT MAX(created_Date)
                      FROM  ProductionHistory 
                      GROUP BY TeamID
                      )
```

That's fine, here is the result:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to ignore the `assigned_to` null then find latest record for team?
2. When there is only one record with `assigned_to` null for team, let's consider that.

For example: for Team_id 5 there is only one record with assigned_to null, we don't have any other record for team_id 5 with assigned_to set some value.
So we have consider this.

For team id 3 query result should ignore the record 4 (though max date), query result should contain record 2.

Here is the final result I am expecting:

[image]

Comment: Note that posting images in your question is generally a bad idea. For one, they are often blocked (like for me here at work) . But also, what if I want to reproduce your setup - you expect me to type it all in when you could have just put in the table structure as text? The same goes for the sample data. If you make it easy for us to replicate your problem you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Agreed with Turophile - You'd definitely get answers quicker with raw text.  However, the screen shot did help answer Ben's question - you're using SQL server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      TicketID INT ,
      TeamID INT ,
      StatusID INT ,
      created_Date DATETIME ,
      Assigned_to NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  @t
VALUES  ( 10000, 2, 7, '2015-03-26 01:48:00.000', 'W3ER45' ),
        ( 10000, 3, 7, '2015-03-26 05:48:00.000', 'YU67IO' ),
        ( 10000, 2, 9, '2015-03-26 03:48:00.000', 'HJKO98' ),
        ( 10000, 3, 9, '2015-03-27 03:48:00.000', NULL ),
        ( 10000, 4, 11, '2015-03-23 03:48:00.000', 'GHR67' ),
        ( 10000, 5, 11, '2015-03-27 02:12:56.910', NULL );


;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TicketID, TeamID ORDER BY CASE
                                                              WHEN Assigned_to IS NULL
                                                              THEN 1
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                              END, created_Date DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  TicketID ,
            TeamID ,
            StatusID ,
            created_Date ,
            Assigned_to
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Output:

```
TicketID    TeamID  StatusID    created_Date            Assigned_to
10000       2       9           2015-03-26 03:48:00.000 HJKO98
10000       3       7           2015-03-26 05:48:00.000 YU67IO
10000       4       11          2015-03-23 03:48:00.000 GHR67
10000       5       11          2015-03-27 02:12:56.910 NULL
```

Comment: Perhaps the same hero that downvoted me?  Our answers are nearly identical.  OP, if they're not working, can you clarify the results you're looking for?

Comment: ticket teamid statusid created_date assigned_to rn
10000 2 9 March, 26 2015 03:48:00 HJKO98 1
10000 2 7 March, 26 2015 01:48:00 W3ER45 2
10000 3 7 March, 26 2015 05:48:00 YU67IO 1
10000 3 9 March, 27 2015 03:48:00 (null) 2
10000 4 11 March, 23 2015 03:48:00 GHR67 1
10000 5 11 March, 27 2015 02:12:56 (null) 1
 Record Count: 6; Execution Time: 19ms View Execution Plan  link

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer.I did it with cursor

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( TicketID     INT
,                  TeamID       INT
,                  StatusID     INT
,                  created_Date DATETIME
,                  Assigned_to  NVARCHAR(MAX) )
DECLARE cur CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT [TeamID]
FROM TT
DECLARE @i int
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT_BIG([TeamID])
        FROM TT
        WHERE [TeamID]=@i)>1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @T
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM [dbo].[TT]
        WHERE [TeamID]=@i AND [Assigned_to] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY [created_Date] DESC

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @T
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TT]
        WHERE [TeamID]=@i

    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i
END
SELECT TicketID
,      TeamID
,      StatusID
,      Assigned_to
,      created_Date
FROM @T
GROUP BY TicketID
,        TeamID
,        StatusID
,        created_Date
,        Assigned_to

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

[image]